# Does someone know the short cut for this button in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

right bottom in the screen shot

[image: the button]

I know I can find it in <kbd>**Cmd**</kbd>+<kbd>**,**</kbd> but I don't know its name, hide something??

in Xcode 6

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want but maybe it could help. You have:

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> to show/hide debug area

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to activate console